# Which instruction is faster?

Tags: javascript, performance

If I have a)

```
console.log("I am faster")
```

and b)

```
var string = "I am faster"

console.log(string)
```

Which **console.log** call would be most likely to execute faster, a or b?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: You will not be able to time the difference between setting up a variable or not, compared to the huge amount of work that `console.log` needs to do to print something to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Following the gentle advice Tripp Kinetics gave in the comments, I ran this in node.js:

```
var a = process.hrtime()
console.log("I am faster")
var a1 = process.hrtime(a)
console.log("Total a: %d ns", a1[1])

const str = "I am faster"

var b = process.hrtime()    
console.log(str)    
var b1 = process.hrtime(b)    
console.log("Total b: %d ns", b1[1])

if(a1[1] < b1[1])
    console.log("A is actually faster")
if(b1[1] < a1[1])
    console.log("B is actually faster")
else
    console.log("Holy shit")
```

and, as it turns out, b method is always about 10 miliseconds slower.

Now, **is hard-coding always faster?** I'll find out...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use b, even though it might be a few nanoseconds slower, it no not recommended that you hardcode.

Using b) would mean that you can keep reusing your `string`. Instead of just needing to retype to print the same string again.